# CSS: border-bottom on last li in multiple columns ul appears at wrong position

Tags: css

I have `<ul>` with 2 columns.

`border-bottom` of the last item in first column appears at the top of the second column.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6b7bkomo/

```css
ul {
  column-count: 2;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
  <li>g</li>
</ul>
```

Only happens with odd number of list items.
Happens in Chrome and Edge, does not happens in FireFox.

Why does it happen?

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. All relevant code belongs directly into your question.

Comment: Please add the relevant code as a snippet, there is a tool for that in the editor with <>-symbol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Columns - force break if element is at bottom of column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657364/css-columns-force-break-if-element-is-at-bottom-of-column)

Comment: or [CSS column count causing items to split columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308627/css-column-count-causing-items-to-split-columns)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to add `break-inside: avoid-column;` to your `<li>` element:

```css
ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
     -moz-column-count: 2;
          column-count: 2;
}  
li {
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
  <li>g</li>
</ul>
```

You define two columns, so the 7 `<li>` elements are equal moved to these two columns. The fourth row starting on the first column and ending in the second column (50% on first column / 50% second column).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `column-break-inside` inside `li` element

```css
ul {
  column-count: 2;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  column-break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
  <li>g</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Check the below code; this may help you. I checked this code; it is working 
>      fine.

```
<style>
.menus 
{
    column-count: 2;
}

.menus li 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -moz-page-break-inside:avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
  }
</style>

<ul class="menus">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
  <li>g</li>
</ul>
```